# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context attributed text in Swift 4

Tags: swift4, nsattributedstring

I am using a font in the same in attribute: , it is giving  above error

```
do {
        let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 18.0)! ]


        let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(data: ("Some String HTML".data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: false)!)!,options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                       .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                             documentAttributes: nil,attributes: myAttribute)
        self.NoAccessMessage.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16.0)
        self.NoAccessMessage.attributedText = attrStr

    } catch let error {

    }
```

Please check if any help is required

Comment: There is no method `init(data:options:documentAttributes:attributes:)`, there is `init(data:options:documentAttributes:)` So remove `,attributes: myAttribute`. Also  Swift3 doesn't use `NSAttributedStringKey` if I remember correctly, it's introduced in Swift 4. So tag issue? Side note, don't name your variable starting with an uppercase: `NoAccessMessage` => `noAccessMessage`.

Comment: @Larme But that is the question , how can I achieve my attribute font in Swift 4

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. You have two fonts, and you try to apply both of them on the attributedString. What do you want?

Answer (score 2):

You are combining two different things. You can *either* apply an attribute to a string *or* read some HTML. Not both.

Perhaps you mean this:

```
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 18.0)! ]
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "howdy there", attributes: myAttribute)
```

Or perhaps you mean this:

```
let html = "<p>howdy <b>there</b></p>"
let htmldata = html.data(using: .utf8)
let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(data: htmldata!, options: [.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
```

Make up your mind which it is.

Comment: Of course, you could do one followed by the other. The trouble is you have given no indication what problem you’re _really_ trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can Apply both things **(Swift 4 Code)**

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtWv1: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var txtWv2: UITextView!

class SampleViewController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Sample HTML Text

    let html = "<ul> <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
               adipiscing elit.</li> <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris 
               eurisus.</li> <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li> 
               </ul>"

    do {

        let attrStr = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: html.data(using: 
            String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: false)!,
            options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                      .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], 
                      documentAttributes: nil)

        // here is Your Attributed String
        txtWv1.attributedText = attrStr

        // Change Font or Color as per your requirement
        attrStr.setFontFace(font: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 20)!,color: UIColor.red)
        txtWv2.attributedText = attrStr

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

  }

}
```

You need to Create the Extension of `NSMutableAttributedString` as Following

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

   func setFontFace(font: UIFont, color: UIColor? = nil) {

     beginEditing()

     self.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length)) { (value, range, stop) in
        if let f = value as? UIFont, let newFontDescriptor = f.fontDescriptor.withFamily(font.familyName).withSymbolicTraits(f.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits) {
            let newFont = UIFont(descriptor: newFontDescriptor, size: font.pointSize)
            removeAttribute(.font, range: range)
            addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
            if let color = color {
                removeAttribute(.foregroundColor, range: range)
                addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
             }
         }
     }
     endEditing()
    }
}
```

Output is :
[image]