# Swift ios NSAttributedString Link in TableView not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsattributedstring

```
extension String {    
    func accentTagAndLink(tags:Array<String>) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

        let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        var NSContents = self as NSString

        for tagChild in tags {
            if !tagChild.starts(with: "<") {
                let range = NSContents.range(of: "#" + tagChild)
                var changeString = ""

                for _ in 0..<tagChild.count {
                    changeString += "$"
                }

                NSContents = NSContents.replacingOccurrences(of: tagChild, with: changeString, options: .literal, range: range) as NSString
                attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: tagChild, range: range)
                attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor(red: 79/255, green: 205/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1), range: range)
            }
        }

        return attributedString
    }
}
```

**tableviewCell**

```
class PostCell: TableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var postContent: UITextView!
}
```

**in mainViewController**

```
class PostViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = postTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        let post = postList[indexPath.row]
        let tags = (post["Content"] as! String).FindTagAtString()
        cell.postContent.delegate = self
        cell.postContent.isSelectable = true
        cell.postContent.isEditable = false
        cell.postContent.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.link
        cell.postContent.attributedText = (post["Content"] as! String).accentTagAndLink(tags: tags)
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        print("link")
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("cell")
    }
}
```

`NSLink` in `UITextView` in `TableViewCell`

i want tap Link event return "link"

but only call `TableViewCell` Tab event

always return "cell"

Tell us how to use this i don't know

`TTTAttributedLabel` is worked but crash my code

so make it self Tap link

Is the usage of AttributedString wrong?

help

Comment: Try this one for convert Attributed String https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607109/10150796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Important

> Links in text views are interactive only if the text view is selectable but noneditable. That is, if the value of the UITextView the selectable property is YES and the isEditable property is NO.

I think you forgot to set `isEditable` to false.
[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618606-textview)

Comment: added ` cell.postContent.isEditable = false` but work same as before

Comment: check if `isUserInteractionEnabled` is true, i suppose it will work now.

Comment: problem is isUserInteractionEnabled ,not worked when set isUserInteractionEnabled on interfacebuilder  , add isUserInteractionEnabled programmatically work